# Android client socket is always null

Tags: android, matlab, sockets

I have made client server connection and it connects well but the socket always returns null, I don't know why.

The server is **MATLAB** and has no problem and it runs well. When I try to write the ip of the server in browser it give me the message that the client should receive.

Here is the server code

```
data = 'Hello World..\n'
tcpipServer = tcpip('0.0.0.0',80,'NetworkRole','Server');
set(tcpipServer,'OutputBufferSize',length(data)+1);
fopen(tcpipServer);
fwrite(tcpipServer,data);
fclose(tcpipServer);
```

And here is the client code

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Socket socket;
    TextView txt1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);


       final  byte[] data = new byte[1024];

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.185.10");

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 80);



            socket.getInputStream().read(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        txt1.setText(new String(data));

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is the problem the socket is always equal to null

```
socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 80);
```

Note: It connects to the server but does not receive any thing
and I even have the internet permission in the manifest.

Comment: may be because port 80 is blocked or already occupied.

Comment: i tried many ports and all the same problem. @CodeProcessor